# Run code spread over multiple lines in single keystroke [r]

Tags: r, rstudio

Coding/R noob here.

Say that I want to plot a histogram of my data. To keep it tidy (for me, at least) I've split the parameters over multiple lines:

```
hist(data,
    density=20,     
    ylim=c(0,1),
    xlim=c(0,1),  
    freq=FALSE,
    xlab="X axis",
    ylab="Y axis",
    breaks=25)

curve(dnorm(x,mean, sd),
    col="black",
    add=TRUE,
    lwd=1.5)
```

Now I want to change just one or two of the parameters, and then re-run this whole sequence. If I had everything on one line I could run it all with one keystroke. Now R wants no less than 8 keystrokes to re-run this specific section of code. I could of course select the whole block and run it, but that seems a bit fiddly. I could also use "run previous", but that also gets a bit messy when superimposing graphs, since R doesn't have an "undo plot", so you need to re-run everything if your line width is too broad the first time around.

Is there another way, a la { } or something?

Comment: RStudio does this.

Comment: *"Now R wants no less than 8 keystrokes..."* Can you please explain what you mean by "single keystroke" that will (1) infer which command in your history, (2) infer which parameter you want to change, and (3) infer to what value you want to change this parameter?

Comment: @Henk, is this an example of a "single keystroke" like `OpenApple-Ctrl-Shift-R-S-Q 27` (weak reference to [Nick Burns, your company's computer guy](http://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/nick-burns-your-companys-computer-guy/n11524))? Seriously, @komodovaran_, this is an IDE thing (not an "R" thing) and possibly resolved by reviewing RStudio's editing-pane [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preview version of RStudio is a lot smarter about statement execution. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on OS X) will execute your whole statement no matter how many lines it's spread over. You can download the preview here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

This should get you down to two or three keystrokes.

If you want to do it with a *single* keystroke, you can annotate the code with a section header and then use RStudio's **Run Code Section** command. More on that here:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections

Answer (score 1):

In R studio select Preferences and click on code. Under editing there is the Execution tick "Execute all lines in a statement".

This will allow you to run all the multiple lines of your single script

Comment: Yes, alternatively if you want to demo to someone step by step and avoid all at one go, simply go to Tools -> Global Options -> Code. Then UNCHECK "Execute all lines in a statement"

Answer (score 0):

In the RStudio version I am using, this has changed again. I fixed it by going to Tools > Global Options > Code. Then checking "Focus Console After Executing Code"